# How does google rank yahoo answers pages?

Tags: database, google-ranking

This might sound kinda strange question but I am puzzled. I was just looking at Yahoo answers and I think the site consists of a template page, which is filled every time with data (questions and answers) drawn from a database table. Does that not mean those pages don't really exist? How can google rank those pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some exceptions, if you can view it, so can Google. From a given page, Googlebot will index the contents of the page then follow any links in the page (again, with some exceptions).

So long as the content of the page is visible with Javascript turned off, it is most likely that Google will be able to read it.

I'm fairly certain that Google does not have some backdoor into the Yahoo answers database/s.

Answer (score 3):

To add to Michael's answer: the vast majority of the pages on the internet are created this way. There's an HTML template that's filled in with data from the database. That's how this stack overflow page is rendered, too :-)

The way the page is constructed doesn't at all matter for Google. What does matter is the resulting HTML. Can Google read it? It can if you can, with Javascript turned off.